# How to install Python Matplotlib 1.5.1 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, python, python3, matplotlib

I want to install matplotlib 1.5.1 for python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

But, when I type in the terminal `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`, I just get matplotlib 1.3.1.

I have tried to use pip to install matplotlib, but I got some errors that weren't easy to solve.

Is there an easy way to install matplotlib 1.5.1 on Ubuntu?

Comment: Rather than guessing what you think the package name should be, `apt-cache search python3 | grep -i matplot`

Answer (score 2):

You could be just 4 terminal commands away from an easy installation, depending on the state of your system.

First, there is always risk breaking from the herd.  My 15.10 system only has python-matplotlib 1.4.1something or other.

You could [download the source](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=f51847d8692cb63df64cd0bd0304fd20)

Once you have satisfied the requirements detailed in the `INSTALL` file (mainly python, numpy, libpng and freetype), you can build matplotlib.

1. `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` *to install all
   dependecies required to build matplotlib*
2. `cd ~/Downloads/matplotlib` *because that is where you unpacked
   the archive*
3. `python3 setup.py build`
4. `sudo python3 setup.py install`

The instructions use default interpreter, I used python3 and mine built/installed without a hitch, your success will depend on the state of your system.  Read the error logs.  They will tell you what went wrong.  Generally involving `sudo apt-get install <lib[some]-dev>`, or pre-emptively,